# Glitch.com with Python

Tags: python, python-3.7, discord.py, glitch-framework

How to create and use Python 3.7 on Glitch.com?
I created a project. Default Python version is old.

---

I used these files to run Python on Glitch:

main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="bot.")
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   print("Bot ready!")
bot.run("TOKEN_HERE")
```

start.sh

```
python main.py
```

requiments.txt

```
discord.py==1.2.3
```

Comment: I don't think Glitch supports Python directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [changing `python` in start.sh to `python3`](https://support.glitch.com/t/how-to-use-python-on-glitch/11201/14).

They seem to have [recently updated the default Python 3 version to 3.7](https://support.glitch.com/t/can-you-upgrade-python-to-latest-version/7980/26).

Answer (score 3):

Okay, [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377286/11887348) is correct, an extension to that.

use `python3 main.py` to run your code.

`glitch` accepts to use `start.sh` file, that runs the start up script.

If you are using some packages, you will need to install them, which we generally do using `pip`. **But**, Glitch `pip` runtime installs those packages in `python 2` directory. So, even after using `python3` in `start.sh` in Glitch project, it doesn't work.

Here's the work around.

**Use Python to install packages.**

Following codes will do:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pip
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 main.py
```

***Add above codes in `start.sh`***

- we're first upgrading pip using python3 (which we usually do)
- Install all packages in `requirements.txt` ( don't forget `s` here, I did :|)
- start the `main.py`

Additionally, if you want to install a package separately, use `python3 -m pip install <package_name>`.

Have fun. Your project just launched successfully.